# Logic for combination of elements from two array ( Javascrip / Typescript )

Tags: javascript, typescript

Two array format mentioned here

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    "elementName": "one"
  },
  {
    "elementName": "two"
  }
]

const arr2 = [
  {
    "type": "RPT_PROPERTY_DEMOGRP",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "HH"
      },
      {
        "label": "HH1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "RPT_PROPERTY_PLAYBACK_TYPE",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "WW"
      },
      {
        "label": "WW1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need a combination for these two like

1. 'one HH WW'

   'one HH WW1'

   'one HH1 WW'

   'one HH1 WW1'

   'two HH WW'

   'two HH WW1'

   'two HH1 WW'

   'two HH1 WW1'

How to write logic for this in js or ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
const
    cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
    arr1 = [{ elementName: "one" }, { elementName: "two" }]
    arr2 = [{ type: "RPT_PROPERTY_DEMOGRP", values: [{ label: "HH" }, { label: "HH1" }] }, { type: "RPT_PROPERTY_PLAYBACK_TYPE", values: [{ label: "WW" }, { label: "WW1" }] }],
    result = [
            arr1.map(({ elementName }) => elementName),
            ...arr2.map(({ values }) => values.map(({ label }) => label))
        ].reduce(cartesian);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a cartesian product: https://eddmann.com/posts/cartesian-product-in-javascript/

```
const set1 = arr1.map(elt => elt.elementName);
const set2 = arr2.map(elt => elt.values.map(val => val.label));
const dataSet = [set1, ...set2];
dataSet.reduce((acc, set) => acc.map(x => set.map(y => [x, y].flatten())).flatten())
```